# HTML Code Not Running After Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar created that is working perfectly but when I try adding text into my body nothing appears. I try giving it a class, changing font color, and background color. But, nothing seems to work. Here is the code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Enforcext</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="http://www.destinygamewiki.com/images/7/72/Enforcer_medal1.png" width="50px">
            <ul class="links">
                <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 15px;"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
                <br/>
                <div class="lt">
                    <div class="dp-click">
                        <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 15px" class="dp-click"><a href="#" class="dp-click">Languages</a></li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <div class="lt">
                <ul class="dp-contents links">
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px; list-style-type: none;" class="nodecor"><a href="HTML.html">HTML</a></li>
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px; list-style-type: none;" class="nodecor"><a href="CSS.html">CSS</a></li>
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px; list-style-type: none;" class="nodecor"><a href="Javascript.html">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px; list-style-type: none;" class="nodecor"><a href="PHP.php">PHP</a></li>
                    <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 25px; list-style-type: none;" class="nodecor"><a href="Java.php">Java</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div class="lt">
            <ul class="links">
                <li style="margin: 5px; margin-left: 15px;"><a href="Contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <body>

    </body>
    <div class="bb">
        <h1>HTML LOLZEEZ FOR THE WIN</h1>
        <h1> HEY </h1>
    </div>
    <script src="Javascript.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: you should put all html tag inside `<body></body>` tag, see the right HTML structure in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp)

Comment: You can do without a head but not a body. Second ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply take the code:

`<div class="bb">
      <h1>HTML LOLZEEZ FOR THE WIN</h1>
      <h1> HEY </h1>
 </div>`

and you put it in the body tags, it should make it show and it will not effect the styling at all.